# Looking for an identity connecting polylogarithm and polygamma functions of arguments $\frac14$ and $\frac34$

Tags: calculus, reference-request, special-functions, polylogarithm, polygamma

I have a recollection of seeing an identity connecting polylogarithm and polygamma functions of arguments $\frac14$ and $\frac34$. But I don't remember details, and searching my books and the Internet for an hour did not give any results. Could you please remind me this identity (if it exists)?

Comment: Are you sure about $1/4$ and not $1/3$? I am looking at (5) and (7) [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigammaFunction.html); recall that Clausen function is essentially imaginary part of the dilogarithm...

Comment: Definitely $1/4$. IIRC, there was a difference of polygammas of variable order $\nu$ at points $3/4$ and $1/4$ expressed via $\sum$ of polylogarithms depending on $\nu$.

Comment: Closest I can find is the reflection relation for the polygamma function: $$\psi_n(1-z)-(-1)^n \psi_n(z)=(-1)^n \pi \dfrac{d^n}{dz^n}\cot \pi x.$$ Maybe a special case of that can be written in terms of polylogs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have not found a source, but I think I reconstructed it correctly:
$$\psi^{(n)}\!\left(\tfrac34\right)-\psi^{(n)}\!\left(\tfrac14\right)=(-1)^n\,4^{n+1}\,n!\,\,\Im\operatorname{Li}_{n+1}(i),\ n\in\mathbb N.$$
In the source where I saw it, the imaginary part was probably written as a difference of two polylog terms.

It can be proved using:

- http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygammaFunction.html, (5)
- http://dlmf.nist.gov/25.11, 25.11.31
- Gradshteyn—Ryzhik, 3.523
- http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendresChi-Function.html, (2), (4)

Comment: You may be interested by two papers from Kölbig : ["The polygamma function $\psi^{(k)}(x)$ for $x=\frac 14$ and $x=\frac 34$"](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042796000556) and the generalization ["The polygamma function and the derivatives of the cotangent function for rational arguments"](http://cds.cern.ch/record/298844/files/cn-96-5.pdf).

Comment: These are very interesting papers. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you liked them @Vladimir. Junesang Choi has also this paper ["Values of the polygamma functions at rational arguments"](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/231070217_Values_of_the_polygamma_functions_at_rational_arguments). Cheers,